# when I am running "gulp build" I get his error?

Tags: gulp

```html
[09:39:48] 'aurelia-build-translations' errored after 30 ms
[09:39:48] SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at processTranslationFile (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:18:28)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:186:9)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:12:5)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\aureliabuild\tasks\build.js:45:3)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
    at Gulp.onTaskEnd (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:75:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
    at f (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
[09:39:48] 'build' errored after 11 s
[09:39:48] SyntaxError in plugin 'run-sequence(aurelia-build-translations)'
Message:
    Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
Stack:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at processTranslationFile (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:18:28)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:186:9)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:12:5)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\aureliabuild\tasks\build.js:45:3)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
    at Gulp.onTaskEnd (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:75:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
    at f (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
[09:39:48] 'aurelia-build' errored after 171 ms
[09:39:48] SyntaxError in plugin 'run-sequence(build)'
Message:
    Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
Stack:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at processTranslationFile (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:18:28)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:186:9)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:12:5)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\aureliabuild\tasks\build.js:45:3)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
    at Gulp.onTaskEnd (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:75:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
    at f (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
[09:39:48] 'aurelia-build' errored after 172 ms
[09:39:48] SyntaxError in plugin 'run-sequence(aurelia-build-translations)'
Message:
    Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
Stack:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at processTranslationFile (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:18:28)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:186:9)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\shared\translations.js:12:5)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\aureliabuild\tasks\build.js:45:3)
    at module.exports (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
    at Gulp.onTaskEnd (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:75:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
    at f (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at c:\wamp64\www\desygner-business\builder\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
```

some thing about 'aurelia-build-translations' ,I put
var setting = fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8');
 var settings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(baseTranslationFiles))

for getting file name:it has returned me undefind!!
[image]

SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1497

I have no clue to find what file has error,I have checked all jsons file,unfourtunatly I could not find any error on files,Could you please help me?

Comment: You’ll likely get a better response if you replace the image of the output with text; it’s easier to read and quickly search through.

Comment: @msbit  I have changed it

Answer (score 0):

Without actually having your JSON to view it's hard to make a concrete call here, but when I've seen similar errors before it's generally down to one node of other in the JSON having a trailing comma ',' somewhere or other

Have you tried validating the file - something like jsonlint.com is pretty good at showing you where you have an error

Comment: lobo said:    1-Find translations gulp Error file
2-
 try {
      var baseContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(baseTranslationFile, 'utf8') || '{}');
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(baseTranslationFile);
    }